# Does Loadrunner (VUGen) support 2-Factor Authentication?

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner, vugen, microfocus

Our application uses OKTA. We have to login to the OKTA portal, which sends a code to our mobile device (via SMS or the OKTA app). This code is then entered into a prompt. If the code is valid, we are then able to go to our test application.

Does Loadrunner support the scripting and handling of applications that use 2-factor authentication as part of their login protocol? If so, can anyone point me to a guide/documentation that explains how this is handled?

Thank you!

Comment: If your two factor authentication fails to scale, who do you report that to?  Do you have a performance SLA in your OKTA Contract?

Comment: Get a virtual device through a VOIP provider.  Login to their web based account portal to receive the text as part of your HTTP virtual user